# REST api best practices versioning without duplicating code

Tags: node.js, api, rest, version, nodes

I'm writing an api on my own in Node for study purpose and practice. I'm struggling on how should I implement the versioning.
Example:
Routes from v1

> api/v1/products calls v1/ProductController
> api/v1/clients calls v1/ClientController

Routes from v2 - The only routes with changes (code)

> api/v2/clients calls v2/ClientController

What is the best practice to manage the behavior of v2 without duplicating codes from v1 to v2. My thinking/solution is:

> api/v2/products -> point to -> 'v1/ProductController' or 'api/v1/products'

Is that right?

Implementing that way, I can manage default versions for my mobile app. Example, mobile app version 2 always use api/v2.
And it doens't need to point to v1 or v2 depending of the action.

In terms of performance, in Node, if I register all routes of v1 also on v2, could that use more memory or cpu usage?

Answer (score 0):

If you release version 2 of your api and nothing has changed from version 1 but you want your client app to use the latest version, your backend should simply route the endpoint to the same code that version 1 is using. I do this with Wirespec. Wirespec is a free online service that lets you create APIs and deliver responses at customizable endpoints. It supports letting you define multiple versions for an endpoints. You can even attach multiple endpoints to the same api, in the way you've described. Wirespec's api response generation service runs on Node.js.

Visit https://wirespec.dev

You can play around with this service to get a feel for how you can create endpoints that support multiple versions. What is also nice is that you can filter your A{PIs by version numbers.